# Insert into MySQL only unique values when part of a loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert, unique

I have a foreach loop that is going through an array stored in a session.  It is checking in a table whether or not it that value exists.  If it does not, then it is inserting it into another table.   This works great.  However, due to their being many duplicates in the first table - I'm ending up with many duplicates in the second table.   Here is my code:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$getAreaCodes = $_SESSION['area_code'];

    // Start Foreach Loop.  For every area code in session, get it's area code from the zip_zip table

    foreach($getAreaCodes as $value) {

        mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
        $query_getAC = sprintf("SELECT area_code FROM zip_zip WHERE area_code = $value", GetSQLValueString($colname_getAC, "text"));
        $getAC = mysql_query($query_getAC, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC);
        $totalRows_getAC = mysql_num_rows($getAC);

            // If it does NOT exist, insert it into zip_areacodes.
            if (empty($row_getAC)){
                $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO zip_areacodes (area_code, date, type) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    GetSQLValueString($value, "text"),
                    GetSQLValueString($today, "text"),
                    GetSQLValueString("bad", "text"));                          
                    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
            }
    }
```

How can I make this insert statement only insert the $value once instead of multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't add unique constraint to keep data integrity, you must perform a select on zip_areacodes looking for values you wanna insert.

If you wanna eliminate duplicates from source table try [Eliminate duplicates...](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/12/12/remove-duplicate-entries-rows-a-mysql-database-table/)
Then add unique constraint key.

If you wanna things running on even if are wrong use try...catch statement and avoid rise an exception, but this it's very ugly solution.

Comment: What do you mean, create select another recordset on zip_areacodes and  put those values into an array and then insert the data if it doesn't exist or something?

Comment: Yes, that it's. If record don't exists, you could insert and avoid duplicates.

Comment: Do using foreach loops such as that, for records numbering in the 10,000s slow down a dedicated server much?  Or is that negligible at that size?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply alter your database and add an Unique constraint ?

Comment: That creates an error.  I tried to add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE area_codes = $value   But that gave me an error too.